# La soggettività dell'analisi del periodo, seriamente?

Tags: grammar, sentences, grammatical-analysis

Sto svolgendo dell'analisi del periodo e o le cose non mi sono totalmente chiare oppure molto spesso mi capita di avere diverse possibilità di analisi, come se la decisione fosse soggettiva! È mai possibile? 
Io seguo la grammatica del Dardano Trifone (così ci capiamo sulla terminologia).

Di seguito un testo che ho analizzato e i dubbi e le varie possibilità di analisi che ho trovato.

Qui il testo diviso in periodi:

*1) Questa mattina, mentre andavo a scuola, ho incontrato un vecchio compagno delle elementari. 
2) Abbiamo parlato un po' e ad un tratto il mio amico mi ha chiesto se volevo abbandonare per un giorno la scuola e andare con lui al parco. 
3) Ho risposto che non potevo, che per l’assenza avrei dovuto portare la giustificazione, ecc… ma lui ha insistito e mi ha convinto. 
4) Girovagare per il parco era noioso, quindi ci siamo diretti al centro per comprare una pizza. 
5) E qui è accaduta la disgrazia! 
6) Improvvisamente ho visto mio zio, che mi ha guardato con sorpresa, ma non mi ha fermato.
7) Ho notato però che ha subito fatto una telefonata
e ho capito immediatamente a chi telefonava. 
8) Potete immaginare il resto della storia: sgridate e una brutta punizione. 
9) Così è finita la mia avventura che sicuramente non si ripeterà.*

Qui la mia analisi:

**1)** Questa mattina ho incontrato un vecchio compagno delle elementari = principale; 
mentre andavo a scuola = subordinata temporale.

**2)** Abbiamo parlato un po' = principale;
e ad un tratto il mio amico mi ha chiesto = coordinata alla principale;
se volevo abbandonare per un giorno la scuola = subordinata interrogativa; 
e andare con lui al parco = *coordinata alla subordinata interrogativa / subordinata interrogativa*.

Qui mi viene il dubbio che "e andare con lui al parco" possa essere sia una coordinata alla subordinata interrogativa, che una vera e proprio subordinata interrogativa. Di fatto il "se" manca ma potrebbe essere stato omesso per non ripetersi. Allo sesso modo la congiunzione "e" mi fa pensare a una coordinata copulativa. Secondo voi di che si tratta?

**3)** Ho risposto = principale; 
che non potevo = subordinata oggettiva 1 grado;
che per l'assenza avrei dovuto portare la giustificazione = *subordinata causale 2 grado / subordinata oggettiva 1 grado*; 
ma lui ha insistito = coordinata avversativa;
e mi ha convinto = coordinata copulativa.

Qui invece della frase "che per l'assenza avrei dovuto portare la giustificazione" ci sarebbero due interpretazioni. Potrebbe essere una causale: lui non può perché poi deve portare la giustificazione e finirebbe nei guai. Potrebbe però anche essere un'ulteriore subordinata oggettiva, visto che funge in un certo senso da complemento oggetto alla frase "ho risposto".

**4)** Girovagare per il parco = subordinata soggettiva 1 grado;
era noioso = principale; 
quindi ci siamo diretti al centro = subordinata consecutiva 1 grado;
per comprare una pizza = subordinata finale 2 grado.

**5)** Improvvisamente ho visto mio zio = principale;
che mi ha guardato con sorpresa = subordinata relativa di 1 grado;
ma non mi ha fermato = *coordinata avversativa / subordinata relativa 1 grado*.

Qui il dubbio sorge sull'ultima parte. Visto che c'è il "ma" mi viene da dire che è una coordinata avversativa. Però ho pensato anche a una relativa, in cui il "che" è stato omesso. Possibile?

**6)** Ho notato però = principale;
che ha subito fatto una telefonata = subordinata oggettiva; 
e ho capito immediatamente = coordinata copulativa;
a chi telefonava = subordinata oggettiva 1 grado.

**7)** Così è finita la mia avventura = principale; 
che sicuramente non si ripeterà = subordinata relativa 1 grado.

Sono molto grata delle vostre correzioni e opinioni! 
A me parrebbe proprio che la soggettività giochi un certo ruolo nell'analisi, ma in ogni caso spererei di sbagliarmi. Vorrei che ci fosse una sola possibilità di analisi, quella giusta! Voi che pensate?

Comment: Benvenuta e attenta agli accenti, E.V.!

Comment: Eh lo so! Purtroppo ho solo una tastiera tedesca sul pc e non so come cambiarla quindi tutti i miei accenti sono sbagliati!!

Comment: L'errore è stato dirigersi al centro per comprare una pizza, per il resto nulla è spiegato circa cosa facesse questo 'zio' nel parco.

Comment: Spero che qualcuno abbia più tempo di me, che non riesco ad analizzare tutta la tua lunghissima domanda. Al volo, posso solo osservare che a volte è la lingua stessa a essere ambigua e a permettere più di un'interpretazione di una certa frase: scelta l'interpretazione, ne deriva l'analisi. Nei tuoi esempi, la frase «Improvvisamente ho visto mio zio, che mi ha guardato con sorpresa, ma non mi ha fermato» è chiarissima, ma è vero che un parlante italiano la può recepire nei due modi lievemente diversi che dici: [segue]

Comment: potremmo eliminare la (prima) relativa, e la frase reggerebbe, pur non essendo perfetta: «Improvvisamente ho visto mio zio, ma non mi ha fermato». Quindi potremmo senz'altro considerare la seconda parte come una coordinata. D'altronde non è bellissimo quel cambiamento di soggetto esplicitato solo dal senso della frase, e quindi nel periodo completo è forse meglio considerare “non mi ha fermato” come retto dallo stesso “che” che regge “ha guardato”. (In più, personalmente preferirei “mi ha guardata” e “non mi ha fermata”.)

Comment: Qui la lieve ambiguità è solo formale, ma potrebbe essere più sostanziale in una frase come “Gino ha incontrato Pino, che aveva una cravatta viola, e ha finto di non vederlo”. Chi ha finto di non vedere chi?

Comment: Sì, tutta la grammatica è soggettiva. Ci sono molte persone che si arrampicano sugli specchi per affermare il contrario e mantenere un'aura di autorevolezza come insegnanti, ma a una persona con formazione da matematico (e su questo forum ce ne sono parecchie) è evidente. È impossibile trovare una definizione sensata di quasi qualunque termine, e ci sono milioni di eccezioni. Non credo che ci sia speranza di trasformarla in una scienza esatta.

Comment: Sto spezzettando i miei dubbi in piccole domande e le sto ponendo una per volta, così che non c'è bisogno di rispondere a tutta la domanda qui sopra se non si conoscono tutte le risposte.

Comment: @ Federico Poloni  Per criticare una cattiva didattica della grammatica hai proprio  bisogno di un claim così impegnativo _tutta la grammatica è soggettiva_?

Comment: @mario Ammetto che "tutta la grammatica è soggettiva" probabilmente è eccessivo, ma secondo me il tuo tentativo di ridurre la questione a "cattiva didattica" invece è riduttivo. La verità sta da qualche parte in mezzo. (Occhio a non mettere spazi nello username dopo la @, altrimenti non mi arrivano le notifiche -- ho visto il tuo commento per caso)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

L'analisi logica e l'analisi del periodo sono un residuo ormai obsoleto della vecchia cultura "grammaticale" che cercava di chiudere la lingua in tutta una serie di pedantissime regole logiche, su influsso della vecchia grammatica latina. Inevitabilmente per ogni regola ci sono centinaia di eccezioni, perché è impossibile catalogare un'entità così complessa come le lingue naturali.

In età recente c'è stato un forte scontro tra linguisti: tra i sostenitori del vecchio modo, che mettono la grammatica standardizzata al centro, e quelli del nuovo modo, che la considerano nulla di più che una sistemazione di comodo (da usare per lo studio accademico e l'insegnamento), provvisoria e imperfetta, di una materia inevitabilmente magmatica e non incarcerabile in regolette, infatti:

- la lingua si evolve seguendo percorsi del tutto caotici e "creativi" che la portano continuamente a deviare dagli esiti che ci aspetteremmo secondo regole, logica e buon senso (ad esempio: l'accento acuto su "o" ed "e" indica vocale chiusa, quello grave aperto; eppure quando si tratta di "u" e "i" usiamo l'accento grave, anche se sono vocali chiuse); questo significa un continuo proliferare di "eccezioni": ci sono più eccezioni alla regola che regole
- l'ambito dell'esperienza umana descritto dalla lingua è troppo complesso e variegato perché lo si possa racchiudere in regole logiche gestibili da un essere umano (ci hanno provato in molti, a partire da Leibniz, a creare lingue "a priori", matematiche, del tutto inambigue e prevedibili; ma hanno tutti fallito)

La linguistica moderna è oggi in gran parte sulla seconda posizione; ma la scuola segue sempre in ritardo, quindi ancora i ragazzi devono sprecare tempo su queste sciocchezze (e si convincono che la scuola non serve a niente, e come dargli torto?).

Un esempio tratto da [Pallotti, Descrivere le lingue](http://for.indire.it/global_lms/uploads/pon_linguistica1213/19972.zip): "la casa va a fuoco". "a fuoco" che complemento è? di sfiga? Un insegnante di scuola dirà complemento di moto a luogo figurato; il "figurato" è un po' la discarica di tutto quello che non si sa catalogare.

Per concludere, lasci perdere: è davvero una questione soggettiva.

Comment: Capisco e in gran parte condivido, ma mi rimane da capire come, sotto tale impostazione, io possa qualificare in modo giustificato che una frase sia, o appaia,  sgrammaticata: _io credo che egli è un asina con gli ali_.

Comment: Nel tuo esempio si tratta di morfosintassi, non di analisi: credo vuole il congiuntivo, ali l'articolo femminile, ecc. La morfosintassi indaga i rapporti di collocazione tra le parole.  L'analisi logica/del periodo è tutta un'altra cosa: il tentativo "filosofico" di catalogare l'uso linguistico all'interno di categorie astratte (per giunta con velleità universalizzanti).

Comment: Naturalmente non è tutto campato in aria: in "vado a casa" ha senso dire che "a casa"  è moto a luogo.  Ma queste relazioni sono interamente *semantiche* (scaturiscono automaticamente dal significato della parola), non grammaticali.

Comment: Non sono un linguista, e ovviamente si tratta di problematiche molto ampie e complesse, ma i due tuoi _perché_ mi sembrono troppo generici. Spiegare i   _percorsi del tutto caotici e "creativi"_ non sarà più difficili dello spiegare l'evoluzione delle specie animali, o no?, e pur ci tentiamo.

Comment: @ perché _secondo ragione_? Secondo uso e pratica consolidata non potrebbe comunque fondare una concezione oggettivista della grammatica?

Comment: È senz'altro possibile tracciare oggettivamente ciascun esito linguistico (sempre che ci siano dati a sufficienza, che non è affatto scontato). Il punto è che ci si rende subito conto che questi tracciati non possono essere riconciliati tra loro a formare un sistema logico, che è quello che vorrebbe l'analisi logica. Ci troviamo con costrutti come "andare a fuoco" e "andare in malora" che non possono essere ricondotti al moto a luogo; quindi serve una nuova categoria; e per un altro costrutto un'altra ancora, e così via: come proliferano le eccezioni, proliferano le categorie

Comment: Il reale è troppo variegato e sfumato e mutevole; non si può chiudere agevolmente in quella ventina di complementi che ci offre l'analisi logica. E non ha nemmeno senso farlo: volevano farlo certi filosofi-logici (consiglio [questo articolo](http://www.joerg-rhiemeier.de/Conlang/auxlang-design.html) molto semplice ma accuratissimo); noi vogliamo invece capire la storia di ogni singolo costrutto, senza cercare di trasformare la lingua in un sistema inevitabilmente semplicistico

Comment: @@mus_siluanus  ritornando alla questioen didattica, come non confondere lo studente adolescente, ma fornigli un metodo di analisi grammaticale (o linguisitca) (assumendo che la consapevolezza linguistica aiuta allo studio)?

Comment: @mario questa è una domanda spaventosamente difficile! premesso che di teoria dell'insegnamento so molto poco, a buon senso mi chiedo se non sarebbe di gran lunga più fruttuoso dedicare le ore risparmiate eliminando l'analisi al confronto *pratico* con le altre lingue, specialmente extraeuropee; scoprire ad esempio che non è affatto scontato che il genere distingua tra maschio e femmina, o che il verbo debba essere coniugato in base al tempo; notare come una stessa radice latina si specializza con significati diversi nelle varie lingue romanze; capire come la struttura fonetica influisce..

Comment: .. sulle strutture morfologiche e sintattiche (vedi ad esempio i composti cinesi, con scoiattolo che si traduce "pini-topo" e la necessità di sviluppare parole bisillabe per fronteggiare l'omofonia dilagante), etc etc.. insomma riflettere sulla lingua riflettendo come altre lingue profondamente diverse (o profondamente simili, che è altrettanto interessante in altri modi) rendano la stessa struttura o lo stesso concetto o la stessa inclinazione verso l'oggetto

Comment: io penso che un metodo simile non solo avrebbe risultati eccezionali nello sviluppare la comprensione e la capacità d'uso della lingua, ma sarebbe anche tremendamente stimolante, anche per degli adolescenti (che nella mia esperienza sono più che pronti a entusiasmarsi per quello che merita entusiasmo). Il problema è che un simile lavoro richiede all'insegnante una formazione altrettanto eccezionale, essenzialmente autodidatta... (riguardo al genere, cui accennavo prima, mi riferivo al fatto che in alcune lingue il genere distingue tra animato e inanimato, in altre tra umano e non umano, ecc)

Comment: con un metodo simile le strutture grammaticali dell'italiano sarebbero imparate passivamente, in modo divertente o comunque piacevole (non a caso la letteratura aneddotica ha sempre avuto grande successo), e per giunta con una profondità di comprensione verso il linguaggio e il suo funzionamento che al momento nemmeno gli studenti universitari ottengono se non attraverso lo studio autonomo

Comment: e un'altra cosa: usare testi reali, magari anche da blog e copioni di film, invece che le frasette insulse e finte tipiche delle grammatiche; se poi si riuscisse a trattare un po' di analisi stilistica, già che ci siamo... notare che una frase ci ha coinvolti, e dunque cercare insieme di analizzarla per capire cos'ha di speciale, magari delle parole combinate ad arte per sfruttare effetti evocativi, etc

Comment: @@mus condivido l'atteggiamento di fondo, a un altro forum per la discussione nel merito e per eventuali dettagli. Grz risposte, alla prossima.

Comment: Figurati! Alla prossima!