# Analisi logica frase

Tags: sentences, grammatical-analysis

Sto ripassando l'analisi logica e ho un dubbio in questa frase:

> Domenica andremo a pesca;

“a pesca” è un complemento di luogo?

Ho un'altra domanda:

> La scuola è a pochi minuti da qui;

“a pochi minuti da qui” è un complemento di quantità o di tempo?

Comment: Nella risposta di @mus_siluanus a [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6259/la-soggettività-dellanalisi-del-periodo-seriamente) e relativi commenti ci sono alcune considerazioni interessanti sull'arbitrarietà dell'analisi logica scolastica, sia rispetto alla pratica quotidiana della lingua che rispetto allo studio linguistico accademico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- “a pesca” -> complemento di fine o scopo ('al lago' sarebbe stato di luogo)
- “a pochi minuti da qui” -> complemento di tempo determinato ( quando? in che tempo? ) + attributo

Comment: Non direi proprio, nessuno dei due.